# Snowflake: concatenate 4 tables data into singe table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have 4 tables, all are same w.r.t columns and  column types.

Example: the below are the table names

```
data_2017
data_2018
data_2019
data_2020
```

For ease of data ingestion we have to create seperate tables for each year.

Now I want to concatenate all the tables into one table

How can i do this in snowflake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `UNION ALL` to create a new table/view

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE/VIEW concatenated_data
AS
SELECT * FROM data_2017 UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM data_2018 UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM data_2019 UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM data_2020;
```

`*` should be replaced with actual column names.